# in_array returns True from a value that not exists

Tags: php

```
$arr = [ 'foo'=>true, 'bar' ];

var_dump( in_array('some',$arr) );
```

Why `var_dump` returns `true` if `some` does not exists in `$arr`?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). If you want a strict comparison you should set the 3rd parameter to `true`, else `'some' == true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in_array()` check for the **values** of the **arrays**.

If you are setting a **value** as `true`, it will return `true` because of that, unless, as mentioned by @AymDev before, you set the third parameter to be strict.

Answer (score 0):

just like this In your case

```
$arr =  array('foo'=> 'true', 'bar'  );
or 
$arr =  array('foo'=> 1, 'bar'  );
```